# How do I check the value of the attribute aria-disabled as true or false in Krypton using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I tried:

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id='StandardSave'][aria-disabled='true']"
```

but still won't work.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Does it throw an error, exception, ...? We will need the relevant HTML (as text) in order to see if your locator is correct. Please edit your question and add the full error/exception message along with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To check the value of the attribute **aria-disabled** you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `id`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("StandardSave"))).getAttribute("aria-disabled"));
  ```
- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#StandardSave"))).getAttribute("aria-disabled"));
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='StandardSave']"))).getAttribute("aria-disabled"));
  ```